# Filtering array with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to filter some objects in my attempt to understand JS better and I'm using underscore.js

I come from a C# background and am used to LINQ however underscore is not quite the same.

Can you help me filter out this array based on the defined test, the issue I'm having is the array property on the array. The `Where` operator is diffeernt to C# which is what I'd normally use to filter items.

```
products = [
       { name: "Sonoma", ingredients: ["artichoke", "sundried tomatoes", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "Pizza Primavera", ingredients: ["roma", "sundried tomatoes", "goats cheese", "rosemary"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "South Of The Border", ingredients: ["black beans", "jalapenos", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "Blue Moon", ingredients: ["blue cheese", "garlic", "walnuts"], containsNuts: true },
       { name: "Taste Of Athens", ingredients: ["spinach", "kalamata olives", "sesame seeds"], containsNuts: true }
    ];

it("given I'm allergic to nuts and hate mushrooms, it should find a pizza I can eat (functional)", function () {

      var productsICanEat = [];

      //This works but was hoping I could do the mushroom check as well in the same line
      var noNuts = _(products).filter(function (x) { return !x.containsNuts;});

      var noMushrooms = _(noNuts).reject(function(x){ return !_(x.ingredients).any(function(y){return y === "mushrooms";});});


      console.log(noMushrooms);

      var count = productsICanEat.length;
      expect(productsICanEat.length).toBe(count);
  });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to remove the `!` from the `reject` callback so that it look like this:

```
var noMushrooms = _(noNuts).reject(function(x){ 
    return _(x.ingredients).any(function(y){return y === "mushrooms";});
});
```

Otherwise you're rejecting the ones that *don't* contain mushrooms instead of those that do.

Comment: DOH! Thanks that did it. Any ideas if its possible to chain it? I've tried but no luck

Comment: you need to do `_.chain(list)` first then you can chain your functions all day long - like so `_.chain(myArray).filter(function(){ }).reject(function(){ })`  http://underscorejs.org/#chaining

Comment: Looks like .any() is depricated.  Underscore now has a _.some() method that returns true or false based on whether there are "some" matches.

Comment: @skrile It's not deprecated, `any` is the alias of [`some`](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#some).

Comment: Thanks for that @JohnnyHK - I learned something new today  :)

Answer (score 6):

A more concise way to accomplish this would be with underscore's chain() function:

```
var noMushrooms = _(products).chain()
    .filter(function (x) { 
        return !x.containsNuts;})
    .reject(function(x){ 
        return _(x.ingredients).any(function(y){
            return y === "mushrooms";
        });
    })
    .value();
```

Comment: You don't need to chain, but chaining this way makes it very clear what operations you are doing to your list.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get my solution all wrapped up into one filter call so thought I'd post it:

```
products = [
       { name: "Sonoma", ingredients: ["artichoke", "sundried tomatoes", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "Pizza Primavera", ingredients: ["roma", "sundried tomatoes", "goats cheese", "rosemary"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "South Of The Border", ingredients: ["black beans", "jalapenos", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "Blue Moon", ingredients: ["blue cheese", "garlic", "walnuts"], containsNuts: true },
       { name: "Taste Of Athens", ingredients: ["spinach", "kalamata olives", "sesame seeds"], containsNuts: true }
    ];

 it("given I'm allergic to nuts and hate mushrooms, it should find a pizza I can eat (functional)", function () {

      var productsICanEat = [];

      productsICanEat = _(products).filter(function (x) { return !x.containsNuts && !_(x.ingredients).any(function(y){return y === "mushrooms";});});


      expect(productsICanEat.length).toBe(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

This will give the desired result

```
var no_nuts = _.filter(products,function(item) {
         return !item.containsNuts;
       });

var no_mushroom = _.reject(no_nuts,function(item) {
        return _.any(item.ingredients,function(item1) {
            return item1 === "mushrooms"
        }); 
     });

console.log(no_mushroom);
```

`reject()` does the opposite of `filter()`, and `any()` is equivalent to some method of arrays which returns true when any of the element in the array when passed through a callback returns true.