# filter json from array values with underscore

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I have an array of object that is need to create a filter on. The list contains an owner_id property in the JSON...

At the moment im just looping all in the array, however the list should NOT take the ones where owner_id is equal to one of the values in my filterarray:

```
var filter = "[14657612, 2215375794]";

            $.ajax({
                url: 'myEndPOint',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    var media = data.media;
                    var arr = [];

                    _.filter(media, function(val){
                         //The magic should happen here, only return items that has'nt got an val.owner_id that is in "filter" array
                    });

                    for(i=0; i < media.length; i++) {
                        var thumb = media[i].thumbnail;
                        var html = "<li><img src=" + thumb + " /></li>";
                        arr.push(html);
                    }
                    $(".social-ribbon-target").append(arr);
                    $(".loading").css("display", "none");*/

                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Check this one for reference. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14339601/3264939

Comment: you filter is not array but string

Answer (score 0):

> The magic should happen here

It is actually not magic, but a function that returns `true` or `false` whether the item should be in the returned array.

Assuming that your filter is an array and not a string as it is right now (otherwise you have to parse it with `filter_arr = JSON.parse(filter)`)  you may want to write your filtering function like this:

```js
var filter = ["one",  "two", "three"];

var media = [{owner_id: "one"}];

console.log(_.filter(media, function(item){
    return filter.indexOf(item.owner_id) >= 0;
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm, but it doesn't match anything?

_.filter(media, function(item){
       console.log(filter.indexOf(item.owner_id))
       return filter.indexOf(item.owner_id) >= 1;
      });

Even though, some it the items has item.owner_id to be something from the array of filter?

Comment: Why did you change it to >= 1 ? Have you parsed you string to array accordingly?

Comment: Woop, typing error... However, still, everything returns as false or -1 ?

Comment: indexOf returns -1 if the element is not present in the array, or index of an element

Answer (score 0):

You defined `filter` has a string, instead of an array.

Change:

```
var filter = "[14657612, 2215375794]";
```

To:

```
var filter = [14657612, 2215375794];
```